# Javascript countdown only when page reload

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, countdown

i have opencart module daily deal, but the countdown timer is not working.

function code:

```
<?php
class ModelCatalogSpecialPriceCountDown extends Model {

public function getProductSpecialDates($product_id) {

    (string) $display_output = null;
    (string) $minute = 60;
    (string) $hour = 60 * $minute;
    (string) $day = 24 * $hour;

    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
    }   

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT date_start, date_end  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' AND ((date_start = '0000-00-00' OR date_start < NOW()) AND (date_end = '0000-00-00' OR date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY priority ASC, price ASC LIMIT 1");

    if ($query->num_rows) {

        $time_left = strtotime($query->row["date_end"]) - strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        $days_left = floor($time_left/$day);

        if ($time_left > 0)
        {
            $display_output = getdate();
            $display_output["days_left"] = $days_left;
        }
    }

    return $display_output;

}
}
?>
```

and the code using it:

```
<!-- Countdown  start -->
        <div id="defaultCountdown<?php echo $product['product_id'];?>" class="countdown_dashboard"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#defaultCountdown<?php echo $product["product_id"]; ?>').countdown({ 
                    until: new Date(<?php echo $product['yleft'];?>, <?php echo $product['mleft'];?> - 1, <?php echo $product['dleft'];?>)
                    }); 
            });

        //-->
        </script>
```

My countdown doesn't work, the numbers change only when I refresh the page.

Comment: why minutes, hour, days are string if their values is an integer ?

Comment: Also, try to indent your code correctly, and to keep only the relevant parts please.

Comment: Is this a third party extension (that you have purchased or downloaded somewhere) or is it an extension that you are developing right now? In the first case, please contact the extension developer(s) and ask for support. In the second case do you get any JS error in your JS console?